# Raspberry Pi streaming without being connected to Monitor or TV possible?

Tags: raspbian

I'm working on a project for my undergraduate studies in which I will mount a raspberry Pi on a RC car and hopefully get it to stream to a laptop using wireless adapter. My question is that is it possible to stream without the raspberry pi being physically connected to a monitor or tv?

Comment: Hello and welcome! The answer is probably yes, but the question is also quite broad for stackexchange. Try to narrow it down. (How-to's are not exactly the type of answers you'll get here.)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can look into is using a software called motion. A lot of people use it for RPi security camera projects. By default, the software will record video when it detects motion on a video input. Essentially, you will be turning your Pi into an IP camera. This would require you to have the laptop and Pi on the same wireless network. Then you can just browse to the ip of your Pi/Car/Camera in a web browser and it shows you the camera feed. If you don't want a router involved, you would have to look into other wireless streaming options.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that is it possible to stream without the raspberry pi being physically connected to a monitor or tv?

I presume you mean video and the answer is *yes*.  However, it may be difficult to get low enough latency to make it viable for controlling a remote vehicle -- there may be a lag of several seconds.

Comment: Yeah i meant video and I dont think latency should be an issue since its only a project and the actual latency issues can be listed as future improvements.

Answer (score 0):

This is theoretical but I've been thinking about experimenting with a project like this for a while - here is what I am planning:

Since streaming needs internet, you could go to a Mobile Carrier and get a data-only sim. There is Arduinos that can utilize this sim to give Pi an internet connection. Once established, temporarily log in to the Pi via attaching a monitor for configuration purposes.

A. Find the IP
B. Set up the above mentioned "motion" program for Raspbian and attach a camera to get the video.

Once you have set it up, you can unplug the monitor and head to the URL you found out. If configured correctly, on the right port of that IP Address, you should be able to get the stream.

Again this is theoretical and I have not done any research yet.